# VSCode-Lingua plugin stopped working with nrwl-nx version 15 and Angular version 14

Tags: angular, vscode-extensions, nrwl-nx, ngx-translate, vscode-plugin

I was using the plugin in my NX 13, Angular 12 project. It was working great.
But after upgrading to NX 15 and Angular 14 it stopped working. I've tried to reinstall the plugin but no luck. Any suggestions?